# Nearest node in a tree

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, shortest-path, breadth-first-search

Recent I encountered this problem on trees whose solution I found in O(n*q) . I am thinking if there is much better way to deal this with lesser complexity.

The problem is here as follows :

Given an unweighted tree of 'n' nodes ( n>=1 and n can go to 10<sup>5</sup> ) , Its nodes can be special or non special. Node 1 is always special and rest non special initially. Now ,There are two operations :

1.we can update any non special node to special node by an update operation by ***"U Node_Number"***

OR

2.At any time , we can ask user ***"Q Node_Number"*** which should return that special node in tree closest to "Node_Number".

These operations can also go upto 10<sup>5</sup>.

My Solution :

I thought of creating adjacency list. For operation 1, I can keep record of special or Non special by boolean flag. But for operation 2 , my solution comprises of doing BFS whenever "Q Node_Number" is asked taking "Node_Number" as root to begin my BFS.

But complexity is quadratic. Is this the most optimal way of going about this problem ?

Comment: Since when is BFS quadratic time?

Comment: I am doing BFS for every query of second type to find that special node . So , one BFS for One Query of 2nd type

Comment: And one query is then linear time; what's the issue here?

Comment: I have to process 10^5 queries which can be of type 1 or type 2 . Now here's where my algo slows down . BFS = O(n) , Queries <=10^5 , So , total complexity = O(n*q) ..   quadratic !! specially when n<=10^5 and q<=10^5 .

Comment: Certainly there's an O((n + q) log n)-time solution using dynamic trees, which also happens to support the inverse of Operation 1 (special to not special). The question is what the setter intended...

Comment: @DavidEisenstat , please be a little more elaborate how to use dynamic trees.What algorithm further u r using on them.

Comment: Trust me: you *really* don't want to implement that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an O(n^1.5 + n^0.5 q)-time algorithm via a sqrt decomposition. We need a constant-time distance oracle (this is basically least common ancestors). The idea is, every n^0.5 times a node is made special, perform a breadth-first search from all special nodes, which yields for each node in the tree the closest node that is currently special. On each query, take the closest of (i) the nodes that were special as of the last breadth-first search (ii) the at most n^0.5 newly special nodes.

As I mentioned in the comments, I expect that there's a very complicated O((n + q) log n)-time algorithm via [top trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_tree).

Comment: In simple words ... if we have m queries then perform bfs to update distances in sqrt(m) operations every time and in between if distance is asked , find that using LCA.